# Prevent unmounting in React

Tags: reactjs

Is there anyway in React to prevent the `Widget` component be unmounted and mounted again when we change the `condition` prop?

```
interface FooProps {
  condition:boolean
}

const Foo: React.FC<FooProps> = ({condition}) => {
  const widget = <Widget/>
  
  if(condition){
    return <ComponentA>{widget}</ComponentA>
  }
  
  return (
    <ComponentB>
      <ComponentC/>
      {widget}
    </ComponentC>
  )
}
```

Comment: Because its parent element has been changed, I doubt there's a way (without some weird hacks) to keep the `widget` the same instance between change states of `condition`. But I might be wrong.

Comment: *Why* do you want this

Comment: The `Widget` is a complex and independent component, it fetches data from server and uses `useQuery` of GraphQL to fetch data. I don't like to refetch data or re-trigger useEffect when I change the `condition` 


I know you may say I can use `fetchPolicy` of GraphQL to stop sending request to server. but as of complexity I cannot show you why really preventing unmounting cal help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It unmounts because the node does not exist in the Virtual DOM anymore. You can not prevent that.

But...

You can make some tricks to make it work

**You can hide it via css**

Instead of conditionally rendering the component, you can conditionally hide it via `display: none`. It will mount the component twice, but it is not gonna unmount between the rerenders if the condition changes

**Use common parent**

If the element has same parent between the renders it won't unmount.

```
 if (condition) {
    return <ComponentA><Widget key="widget"/></ComponentA>;
  }

  return (
    <ComponentA>
      <ComponentC />
      <Widget key="widget" /> 
    </ComponentA>
  );
```

`<Widget key="widget" />`  **key** is necessary. Since children from `ComponentA` compiles into array of react elements, using `key` prevents unmounting of individual elements if their order change. In the first condition `Widget` is the first element, in the second - the second element

**Use Portal**

You can attach Widget to the same node of the Virtual DOM and render it wherever you want using `portals`

```
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom' 

const Example = () => {
    const [s, ss] = React.useState(true)
    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={() => ss((o) => !o)}>click</button>
            <Foo condition={s} />
        </>
    )
}

const Widget = () => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Widget mount')
    }, [])

    return <>widget</>
}

const ComponentA = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactElement }) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('ComponentA mount')
    }, [])

    return <>{children} inside component a</>
}

const ComponentC = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactElement }) => {
    React.useEffect(() => {
        console.log('ComponentC mount')
    }, [])

    return <>{children} inside component c</>
}

const Foo = ({ condition }: { condition: boolean }) => {
    const ref = React.useRef<any>()
    let content
    if (condition) {
        content = (
            <ComponentA>
                <div ref={ref} />
            </ComponentA>
        )
    } else {
        content = (
            <ComponentC>
                <div ref={ref} />
            </ComponentC>
        )
    }
    return (
        <>
            {content}
            <Portal
                dependency={[condition]}
                elementRef={ref}
            >
                <Widget />
            </Portal>
        </>
    )
}

const Portal = ({ elementRef, children, dependency = [] }: any) => {
    const el = React.useRef<any>()
    if (!el.current) {
        el.current = document.createElement('div')
    }

    React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
        const element = elementRef.current
        element.appendChild(el.current)
        return () => {
            element.removeChild(el.current)
        }
    }, dependency)  // we need to execute this again if the content changes

    return createPortal(children, el.current)
}
```

In this example `<Widget />`:

- is a sibling to the `content` in the `Virtual DOM`
- is a child of `content` in the `real DOM`

In this example if you click the button it will change the content, but the Widget won't unmount

Answer (score 0):

Try using a React memo for the variable that make your component re-render, so it is cached. The reference to that result will remain as long as it doesn't change any of the input parameters. I don't like the idea of displaying that some would use, just try useEffect asynchrony with some control over your variables to avoid rendering.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).